# View column does not recognize using Oracle DBLink

Tags: sql-server, oracle, dblink

I have a problem executing a select on a SQL Server View that I run through an Oracle DBLink. Some columns are not recognized.

```
select 
--a."NumeroRequerimento",                                         -- column not recognized
a."codTipoRequerimento", reencode(a."descricao"), a."data_requerimento", a."cod_ligacao", a."nomeUsuarioLigacao", a."nome_requerente", a."enderecoRequerente", a."enderecoServico",
--a."NumeroOS",                                                   -- column not recognized
a."data_os_emissao", a."situacaoOSTexto", a."situacaoOS", a."equipeOS", 
a."gps_longitude", a."gps_latitude", a."num_os", a."ano_os"
from dbo.os_integracao_gempi@SQLREQUERIM a;
```

Already checked the view in SQLServer and all columns exist

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure those columns are named using ascci?  judging by the spaces they look like unicode.  don't you need an N prefix before unicode?  eg   `a.N"descricao"`

Comment: how can this question be about both sql-server and oracle

Comment: Hogan, there are no spaces between the column names. It is the font design

Comment: Hogan, this view (os_integracao_gempi) exists in SQLServer, I can see it in Oracle through DBLink (SELECT a."codTipoRequerimento", a."data_os_emissao" FROM DBO.OS_INTEGRACAO_GEMPI@SQLREQUERIM a). But some columns (NumeroRequerimento, NumeroOS) are not recognized in this select, and they exist in the view that is in sqlserver

Comment: ok, did you refresh the link after you changed the columns??  Are the columns that don't work only ones with capital letters in them??  What happens when you remove all _ and spaces and lower case letters from your column names, are you able to see all columns then??

Comment: Hogan, I already updated dblink, I have already put all uppercase and lowercase letters in the problematic columns. There are no spaces in the column names, the font type seems to have space. The error persists, don't find the columns.